# Get running time of script in variable (bash)

Tags: bash, time

I'm looking to capture the execution time of an rsync transfer and then store that time in a variable for a later step in my bash script.

I have tried the following:
`ELAPSED=$(time $(rsync -azh source/ dest &> /dev/null))` to no avail. The elapsed time is printed to the screen, but it is not saved in the `ELAPSED` variable.

I have also tried: `ELAPSED=$(/usr/bin/time sh -c "rsync -azh source/ dest &> /dev/null")` but this actually takes the `sh` output and stores that output into the variable, not the time.

Any insights on a better method or corrections to my attempts are appreciated in advance!

Comment: `bash`, or `sh`? If it's bash, you have a `SECONDS` variable that measures time-since-start-of-script (assuming integer seconds is adequate precision).

Comment: BTW, redirecting `time` output to a variable is the subject of [BashFAQ #32](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032).

Comment: ...and as another aside -- all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the shell or operating system; to avoid conflicts, you should use names with at least one lower-case character for your own variables. See relevant POSIX standard at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for the SECONDS variable, Ive been crawling that FAQ#32 link for a bit still no avail yet, and regarding third comment, that's good to know, I thought I was following convention HA!

Comment: Actually, I've got it! Thank you again!